# Deleting post when username matches in javascript

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I'm making a website where you can post images and messages using Meteor. I've been trying to add an event where you can delete posts when the current logged-in user and the poster of the post is the same. Here's what I came up, but it's not working. It keeps saying that it's not my post, even when those two are matching. I think there's a problem with this.currentUser, but I'm not sure how to fix i.

```
Template.posts.events({
'click .delete-task': function (event) {
    if (this.username === this.currentUser) {
        Collections.Appwall.remove({
        _id: this._id
        });
    } else {
        Materialize.toast('This is not your post', 4000);
        return false;
    }
}});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code snippet doesn't provide too much info, but if you're after the username of the currently logged in user, and you're using the standard meteor accounts package, then you could try using

`if (this.username === Meteor.user().username)`

My assumption there is that `username` is an attribute on your data entity, not `currentUser`